# Ask for help using Python's ETH library web3.py and py-evm to splice Receipt trie and encounter problems

Tags: web3.py, python, py-evm

```
def _build_tree(self, transactions, receiptsRoot):
    from rlp import encode, sedes
    from trie import HexaryTrie
    from eth.rlp import receipts, logs
    def zpad(x, l):
        return b'\x00' * max(0, l - len(x)) + x

    block_receipts = []
    for tx in transactions:
        rec = w3.eth.get_transaction_receipt(tx.hash.hex())
        block_receipts.append(rec)

    trie = HexaryTrie(db={})
    for receipt in block_receipts:
        path = receipt.transactionIndex
        logs_list = []
        for l in receipt['logs']:
            log_address = zpad(sedes.big_endian_int.serialize(int(l['address'][2:], 16)), 20)
            data = sedes.BigEndianInt().serialize(int(l['data'].hex()[2:], 16)) if l['data'] == '0x' else b''
            logs_list.append(
                logs.Log(
                    address=log_address,
                    topics=tuple([int(t.hex()[2:], 16) for t in l['topics']]),
                    data=data
                )
            )
        receipt_obj = receipts.Receipt(
            state_root=sedes.BigEndianInt().serialize(receipt['status']),
            gas_used=int(receipt['cumulativeGasUsed']),
            logs=logs_list,
            bloom=int(receipt['logsBloom'].hex()[2:], 16),
        )
        node_byte = receipt_obj.encode()

        trie.set(sedes.BigEndianInt().serialize(path), node_byte)

    if trie.root_hash.hex() != receiptsRoot[2:]:
        raise Exception("Failed to build receipts trie root.")

    return trie
```

why trie.root_hash not equal receiptsRoot[2:]